# How ensure element with z-index 1030 is overlapped by modal window?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar that has a z-index property equal to 1030 but i also have an event that pop-up a modal window that get overlapped by my navbar. i have given it a property of 2030 but it does not fix the issue. How can i ensure it does not happen please?

Comment: Are these elements siblings in the DOM tree? It could help us if you could share some code snippets.

Comment: hi @cs.matyi thanks for coming along. i have found what i was doing wrong. I fixed it by targeting the container of the modal and giving higher value than the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

you can try- by position: absolute to the div you want to show above